# Permission denied when opening file in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have

```
outputToFile(DATA) :-
  open('file.txt',write,Stream),
         write(Stream,DATA),
         close(Stream).
solveGame(P):-solve(P, SOL), outputToFile(SOL),write(SOL).
```

`file.txt` in the same directory of prolog file , When i run it i get

> ℀ERROR: No permission to open source_sink `'file.txt'' (Permission denied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `working_directory(CWD, CWD)` predicate to find out what is the actual working directory (in case it is not the same as the directory of the Prolog file), and make sure you have write permission to it.

Comment: Thank you , ``working_directory(CWD, CWD)`` showed that file in another directory , by the way what do you mean in ``make sure you have to write permission to it ?``

Comment: I meant that at the OS level, the user under which you are running Prolog, has write permission to the directory the program is trying to write to. It depends on the OS (Windows, Linux, etc.). This is probably another question. But, in your case, you should change the working directory to the directory containing your Prolog file, `working_directory(_, "your-prolog-file-directory")`, and this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

What it worked for me was to run SWI-Prolog as an administrator.